# SharePoint Foundation 2010 Solution Deployment

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I was wondering if it is possible to develop a solution using
SharePoint Foundation 2010 with Visual Studio and to directly deploy 
the solution to a Share Point Server 2010 Site?

Answer (score 0):

**To deploy a SharePoint solution to the local SharePoint server**

1. In Solution Explorer, choose the project that you want to deploy.
2. On the menu bar, choose Build, Deploy Solution.
   The .wsp file is created and installed on the local SharePoint server. Also, the features are activated.

[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231565.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Due to SharePoint Foundation is a subset of the SharePoint Server. Yes, it's possible to deploy a Sharepoint Solution that developed on SharePoint Foundation to SharePoint Server with the same version.

Check also [How to Install and deploy a SharePoint (WSP) Solution Package using SharePoint Shell](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/)